# Compress-then-encrypt (CTE) and Encrypt-then-compress (ETC) timing comparison in C++

Tags: c++, encryption, boost, compression, lossless-compression

I want to compare timing of the CTE and ETC schemes, theoretically, as the data in both the schemes are the same (compression ratio of ETC is 1), the timing for compression should be the same in both the cases. Additionally, as compression reduces the amount of data (compression ratio > 1), the time for encryption will also get reduced. As a result, CTE should be faster than ETC.

However, I am getting the opposite results -- my ETC implementation is 5x times faster than CTE. I am reading data from a file and compressing and encrypting it. Any anyone tell me the reason why is this trend being observed? What am I missing?

Compress-then-encrypt code:

```
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "utils.h"
using namespace std;
unsigned char key[] =
{
  0x12, 0x56, 0x34, 0x67, 0x00, 0x11, 0x00, 0x56,
  0x34, 0x45, 0x55, 0x00, 0x67, 0x89, 0x00, 0x50,
  0x56, 0x23, 0x12, 0x45, 0x67, 0x00, 0x15, 0x30,
  0x78, 0x12, 0x89, 0x00, 0x57, 0x12, 0x14, 0x16
 };


//Main function
int main() {
 int temp=0; 
 string path; 

   vector<string> weightLayer;
   
 /* Time function returns the time since the 
        Epoch(jan 1 1970). Returned time is in seconds. */
    time_t start, end;
 //Full neural network compression
 int ii=0;
 for(ii=0; ii<5;ii++)
  {
    string path="/home/nivedita/Documents/Compression/nivedita/models/full/"+to_string(ii)+".txt";
   
   //Compute timing
   string dataCompressed;
   auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();   
   std::ifstream inStream(path, std::ios_base::in);
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> out;
    out.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_compressor());
    out.push(inStream);
    std::stringstream compressed;
    boost::iostreams::copy(out, compressed);
    dataCompressed = compressed.str();
    int i=0;
   while(i < (dataCompressed).size())
          {
             int k=0;
             unsigned char PT[16];   
             while(k<16)
              {
               PT[k] = (dataCompressed[i]);
               int8_t ki = int8_t(PT[k]);
               k++;
               i++;
              }
               AES_KEY key_struct;
               AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &key_struct);
               unsigned char CT[16];
               AES_encrypt(PT, CT, &key_struct);
          } 
     auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
       double time_taken = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count();
    time_taken *= 1e-9;    
    cout << fixed << time_taken << setprecision(9) << "," ;
   
    }

return 0;
}
```

Encrypt-then-compress code:

```
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

unsigned char key[] =
{
  0x12, 0x56, 0x34, 0x67, 0x00, 0x11, 0x00, 0x56,
  0x34, 0x45, 0x55, 0x00, 0x67, 0x89, 0x00, 0x50,
  0x56, 0x23, 0x12, 0x45, 0x67, 0x00, 0x15, 0x30,
  0x78, 0x12, 0x89, 0x00, 0x57, 0x12, 0x14, 0x16
 };


int main(){
 
for(int ii=0; ii <5 ;ii++)
 {
   string fileName;
   string path;
   //vector<int8_t> weightLayer;
   string strWeightLayer;
    path="/home/nivedita/Documents/Compression/nivedita/models/full/"+to_string(ii)+".txt";
     
   auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      std::ifstream inStreamm(path, std::ios_base::in);
      std::stringstream weightLayerr;
      boost::iostreams::copy(inStreamm, weightLayerr);
      // Data is ready, now let us perform AES encryption
          int i=0;
          stringstream inStream;
          string inS;
          
          while(i< weightLayer.size())
          {
             int k=0;
             unsigned char PT[16];   
             while(k<16)
             {
               PT[k] = (weightLayer[i]);
               int8_t ki = int8_t(PT[k]);
               k++;
               i++;
             }
               AES_KEY key_struct;
               AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &key_struct);
               unsigned char CT[16];
               AES_encrypt(PT, CT, &key_struct);
            
               inS += string(CT , CT + 16);
               for(int k=0; k< 16 ; k++)
                  int8_t temp = CT[k];
           }
           
           
    // Compression starts from here      
    
    inStream << inS;
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> out;
    out.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_compressor());
    out.push(inStream);
    std::stringstream compressed;
    boost::iostreams::copy(out, compressed);
    cout << "Original size " << (inStream).str().size() << " Out size " << (compressed).str().size()<< endl;
    string gdataCompressed = compressed.str();
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    double time_taken = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count();
             time_taken *= 1e-9;
         cout << fixed << time_taken << setprecision(9) << "," ;
 }   
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *How* do you benchmark? How many runs do you use to calculate an average? Have you remembered to build both programs with optimizations enabled?

Comment: It is just a comparison, I have used some files with comma-separated integer values as the input. The runs are 100 and optimizations are enabled.

Comment: Try to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (yours is neither minimal nor reproducible). We have no clue what data you are trying to compress and encrypt. Also you are including file operations into your timing benchmark, which often includes unpredictable delays. A much better way to do the timing comparison would be to write a function for compressing as well as for encrypting. Then call and time them in different orders on the same pre-loaded data.

Comment: Why is this a question? It seems like a no-brainer that encrypt-then-compress is going to lead to very bad/no compression unless the ecryption is not cryptographically strong. In all likelihood that makes it useless. Also, more likely to hit worst-case performance cases in the compression algorithm.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The only sensible way to do something _practical_ is to compress data, and then encrypt it. Compressing already encrypted data is compressing random noise - there will be absolutely no compression, it waists compute time and makes the output larger than an input, as most compressors will add headers and footers. Why one call is faster? -  writing correct benchmarking logic is complicated. Have a look at [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark)

Comment: @oleksii I agree with your point; the compression ratio is poor. We don't encrypt and then compress. Still, the experiment aims to compare time as well as compression ratio. My results for compression ratio are correct, I am confused about the timing thing.

Comment: Could it be that because encryption introduces randomness, no compression strategy works properly?
There will be no exhaustive searches in the dictionary, resulting in reduced compression time.